# Do you hand code layout XML file or use WYSIWYG tool to generate it

Tags: android

Back in the day before NetBeans GUI builder (Matisse) is mature enough, I need to perform hand coding, in order to generate a Swing GUI form/ dialog layout.

Now, I no longer need to perform any hand coding for Swing GUI, as Netbeans is able to generate correct Swing GUI code. - A happy NetBeans user :)

Now, for Android App development, I was wondering, **whether most of you are perform hand coding, or using some sort of WYSIWYG tool to generate the layout XML file**?

Till now, I had tried Eclipse + SDK, [DroidDraw](http://www.droiddraw.org/). However, I was quite disappointing with those tools, as non of them able to generate my desired outcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I definitely hand-code it. When I last tried the Eclipse editor, it was so terrible I wouldn't even use it for minor adjustments, as it'd mess up everything I'd previously written.

Comment: I think is a great opportunity for a talented programmer to create such a WYSIWYG tool.

Answer (score 4):

Hand code all the way.  I think its more comfortable for pure dev types like me who would rather become more familiar with the nuts and bolts rather than spend time learning an abstracted tool to do the same.  That said, if a mature, effective Android layout tool shows up, I'll definitely be giving it a shot.

The place where I start disliking WYSIWYG layout editors is usually when you get into fluid layouts, which is critical to Android development.  I know Apple likes using the word "fragmentation" to disparage Android's proliferation across devices.  Its not a bad thing in its nature, but it does create unique problems in designing apps that will provide a uniform experience.  I have yet to see a WYSIWYG editor that addresses this well.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure you'll find a WYSIWYG Android layout editor. DroidDraw is the most viable alternative to Eclipse that I'm aware of.  FWIW here is [an argument against using a WYSIWYG editor](http://designbycode.tumblr.com/post/1079612795/why-dont-wysiwyg-android) from a person on the Google Android team.

Comment: I think that google guy had never use Netbeans Matisse before :)

Comment: Heh, and here's a blog post [arguing in favor of a wysiwyg](http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2010/09/why-you-might-want-wysiwyg-layout.html).

Answer (score 2):

I do use the Eclipse WYSIWYG editor, but only to quickly sanity check layouts that I've hand-coded. I don't do any editing in the Eclipse editor.

My reasons being that:

- As other posters have noted, the
  Eclipse editor generates some
  awful XML.
- I find that it is
  beneficial to understand what is
  going on 'under the hood'- especially
  when the inevitable problems arrive.
- After a a short period of time it
  becomes much quicker.

Answer (score 0):

I throw all of the elements in through the Eclipse plugin WYSIWYG tool then fix everything up through the XML.  As mentioned, the Eclipse plugin isn't very useful.

Answer (score 0):

DroidDraw was very unreliable when I used it. It was really unstable too. I searched and searched for a better answer as I didn't really want to use Eclipse at the time, and I had always got on with the layout designer in Eclipse.

I give in eventually and am using Eclipse again but purely for it's compatibility with Android. The best way I found was hand coding the XML, hooking up a USB cable to your phone and compiling. It's much quicker than the emulator and you get reliable results, at least.

Answer (score 0):

I use both Eclipse plug-in and hand coding. In particular, the Eclipse plugin lets me try out different screen sizes and orientations, which is much faster than build, deploy, test cycles.